# Layer multiple images to display product options

Tags: image, magento, attributes, product

I am needing to create a display where when a user selects the variables of a product, it will layer png images on top of each other in the order so that the user can build out a specific pattern.

Initial image is the base color. Next is the shape. After that is an outline.

Is there a way to build layer on layer with Magento?

This is in community either v1 or 2